# Node.js Oracle DB date returning wrong value

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, date, node-oracledb

I have a date column in my DB. When querying it with SQLDeveloper like so

```sql
SELECT some_date as "Some date",
       cast(some_date as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC' as "Some date UTC"
FROM mytable
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

I get this back
[image: 09-NOV-17 10.00.00.000000000 PM UTC]

When running this code in Node:

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

const dbConfig = {
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  connectString: process.env.DB_TNSNAME,
};

oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig).then(async conn => {
  const result = await conn.execute('SELECT some_date FROM mytable FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY');
  console.log(result.rows[0][0]);
});
```

I get this output: `2017-11-09T21:00:00.000Z`
And when converting this date to local time, for example with moment:

```js
console.log(moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

I get `2017/11/09 23:00:00`

So basically, it seems the date I get when querying the DB through JS is 1 hour behind the date when querying through SQL developer.
I suspect this has something to do with NOV-09 being regular time (so my local time is GMT+2) and the fact that it's currently DST (my local time is GMT+3), but how do I actually fix this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1306  Review https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#datehandling

Comment: @Christopher Jones Not a duplicate, as that isn't event Stackoverflow. Also that is my issue that I made after posting this question

Comment: I was just connecting the dots so people can follow the discussion in whatever place it occurs.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this (https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-16173-fetching-dates-and-timestamps)?

> You can set the environment variable ORA_SDTZ before starting Node.js, for example:

```
$ export ORA_SDTZ='UTC'
$ node myapp.js
```

Comment: For the record, I followed the 2nd option in memodba's provided link and set the client time zone within my Node.JS app:  process.env.ORA_SDTZ = 'UTC'; (before connection is initialised).